# Can't access nested JSON data in my Vue Component

Tags: json, vuejs2

Im trying to figure out why I can't seem to access the following piece of JSON data in my Vue Component.

My project is setup using Vue-cli with the Webpack template and is roughly setup as follows when I run into the problem.

#### Data JSON

This file contains several projects

```
projects: [
  {
    "slug": "page-url-slug",
    "title": "Page title",
    "image": {
      "src": "/static/images/project-image.jpg",
      "alt": "Alt text image"
    }
  }
]
```

#### Router

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/work'
    component: Work
  },
  {
    path: '/work/:slug',
    component: WorkItem,
    props: (route) => ({
      params: route.params
    })
  }
]
```

#### Component JS

```
export default {
  props: [ 'params' ],

  data () {
    return {
      project: {}
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.$http.get('/static/data.json')
      .then((response) => {
        let projects = response.data.projects

        // Find data with same slug param
        for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
          if (projects[i].slug === this.params.slug) {
            this.project = projects[i]
            return
          }
        }

        // Else go back to parent route
        this.$router.push('/work')
      })
  }
}
```

#### Component HTML

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="page">
    <h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
    <img :src="project.image.src" alt="project.image.alt" />
  </div>
</template>
```

When I try to access the **project.image.src** or the **project.image.alt** I keep getting the following error messages:

`[Vue warn]: Error when rendering anonymous component at ...`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined`

I am pretty new to Vuejs and I just can't seem to wrap my mind around the fact this happens.

Comment: I think you need to change your data to a function: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: Sorry i missed that, it is actually in my project. editing my source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add null check as you are loading `project` asynchronously, like this:

```
<img :src="project && project.image && project.image.src" alt="project.image.alt" />
```

When this is being rendered, at that time `project` is not populated and it is still `{}`, which you set it in the beginning.