# Cannot read property of undefinded

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working with Vue and Laravel 5.4.

I have a single post object with a user object inside.

When trying to get any data from that user object inside the post object I get "Cannot read propery of underfinded" even though the data shows fine on the page.

Here is my post object:

[image: post object]

Here where I am calling it:

```
 <div class="pull-left">
     <a href="#">
    <img class="media-object avatar" :src="singlePost.user.photo_url"  alt="img" />
     </a>
```

Its on in a .vue file and everything renders just fine on the page.

I have a user prop that is passed that is the current user of the app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access nested JSON data in my Vue Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853913/cant-access-nested-json-data-in-my-vue-component)

Answer (score -1):

You probably just need to add null check like this:

```
<div class="pull-left">
     <a href="#">
    <img class="media-object avatar" :src="singlePost && singlePost.user.photo_url"  alt="img" />
     </a>
```